# Developing Less CSS locally without a server; "no sheets were loaded"

Tags: javascript, css, less

So I'm trying to extract my own CSS framework from my projects so I can develop it separately.

I have my `index.html` with `less.js` and included my main `.less` file which `@import`s a dozen other files...

However, in the console I get an error for each of my less files:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///path/to/project/src/file.less".`

And a final line that says `Less has finished and no sheets were loaded.`

So I understand this to mean they aren't being served correctly, I normally use Node.js/Express, but I don't want to include all of that in my repo just to develop some CSS. How do I get around this?

I thought about using some node package like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) for development but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary.. Unless I'm wrong?

EDIT: here's my repo, https://github.com/kenmorechalfant/framewerk

Comment: did you set the rel attribute? <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />

Comment: If I try that i get a 'cross origins request' error.

Comment: Edit your question and add your <link ... etc and your folder structure

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kenmorechalfant/fdd76a834c84a5c22c792820304290a5

Comment: Actually, I've just committed it so here's the repo: https://github.com/kenmorechalfant/framewerk

Comment: Don't use `file://`.  You're going to run into a mountain of XSS errors.  Just use a quick static HTTP server.  I use `http-server` with node and most IDEs have one built in.  It is going to be more trouble that it's worth to try and not use a static HTTP server if you don't have a good reason not to.

Comment: @zero298 I suppose that is the proper way to do it.  `http-server` seems to be working just fine and I installed it globally so it's not mucking up my project which is what I was trying to avoid. I think I was just over thinking it. If you submit an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `file://`. You're going to run into a mountain of XSS errors. Just use a quick static HTTP server. I use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) with node and most IDEs have one built in. It is going to be more trouble that it's worth to try and not use a static HTTP server if you don't have a good reason not to.